# max-width table-cell?

Tags: css

Хочу поставить максимальную ширину блока table-cell. Ширину второго блока я не ограничиваю и пускай он занимает все пространство, но первый блок очень надо ограничить. Подскажите.

```css
.table{
display:table;
width:100%;
}
.cell{
display: table-cell;
}
.a{
width:60%;
max-width:10px;/*Не работает*/
background: #ff9;
}
.b{
background: #f9f;
}
```

```html
<div class='table'>
  <div class='cell a'>123</div>
  <div class='cell b'>456</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Для таблиц, встроенных таблиц, ячеек, группы столбцов и т.д., свойство `max-width` и `min-width` не определяется.

Comment: Может можно какой-то костыль придумать?

Comment: Для этого нужно понять поставленную задачу. Вам нужно именно поведение элементов, как табличных?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33318207/max-width-not-working-for-table-cell - вот хорошии пример решение.  `In CSS 2.1, the effect of 'min-width' and 'max-width' on tables, inline tables, table cells, table columns, and column groups is undefined.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.table{
display:table;
width:100%;
}
.cell{
display: table-cell;
}
.a{
width:10px;
background: #ff9;
}
.b{
background: #f9f;
}
```

```html
<div class='table'>
  <div class='cell a'>123</div>
  <div class='cell b'>456</div>
</div>
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. возможно, стоит привести пример использования. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: здесь приветствуются развёрнутые ответы. в которых изложено, например, в чём именно заключается решение: что у автора вопроса «не так», и как добиться того, о чём он спрашивает.